# Timing Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, performance, benchmarking

I would like to add some automated performance test to my Objective-C application. (This is a game, so that I would like to see the current performance of key parts of the engine by simply running a set of tests.) To do this I want to write some timing support routine, something like this:

```
- (void) benchmarkSelector: (SEL) msg onObject: (id) target
{
    // run the selector thousands of times, print detailed stats
}
```

The problem is that I am interested in milliseconds and I am afraid that calling `performSelector` in the benchmarking code would skew the results quite a bit. How would you go around this? Should I go down to `objc_msgSend`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `methodForSelector:`, which returns a function pointer to the actual implementation, like so:

```
IMP methodImp = [target methodForSelector:msg];
for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) {
    NSTimeInterval start = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    methodImp(target, msg);

    NSTimeInterval duration = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - start;
    // Do something with duration
}
```

Note that this strategy is useful for measuring the actual runtime of a method, but if you're going to be calling it with standard Objective-C message-passing syntax, then it might be just as relevant to include the message-passing overhead in your measurements.

Also, note that if the method actually takes any other parameters, you should cast the result of `methodForSelector:` to a function pointer with the appropriate parameters, to avoid unexpected conversion of floats to doubles, etc.  See the [NSObject Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-BAJHGJJE) for more information and examples.

Comment: You are right about including the message-passing overhead, but I was worried that the performSelector: could take ‘a lot’ longer than simply sending the message. After writing the code it does not look that bad – and if I wanted to, I could always back to the IMP. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you get better results if you used 
uint64_t start = mach_absolute_time();
uint64_t duration = mach_absolute_time() - start;

which gives you nanoseconds instead of seconds?

Comment: NSTimeInterval is a double.  The result is expressed in terms of seconds, but has sub-millisecond precision.  Since the OP is looking for milliseconds, I think it's good enough.  But yes, mach_absolute_time() would work too.